# How to avoid filesort for this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, filesort

I need some help in avoiding filesort for this query.

```
  SELECT id 
    FROM articles USE INDEX(group)
   WHERE type = '4' 
     AND category = '161' 
     AND did < '10016' 
     AND id < '9869788' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
   LIMIT 10
```

INDEX(group) is a covering index of (`type`, `category`, `did`, `id`)

Because of `ORDER BY id DESC`, filesort is performed. Is there a way to avoid filesort for such query?

Comment: Are the data types of all those columns numeric (eg. int)? If so, remove the quotes from around all the numbers in your query. This will speed things up significantly.

Comment: @Asaph: Implicit conversion isn't likely to be a big deal; I would remove the single quotes because they give a false impression (assuming the columns data types are numeric)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Are you sure? Even for this part of the query: `did<'10016' and id<'9869788'`? Consider that sorting numbers and strings are different. eg. 1 < 5 < 10, but '1' < '10' < '5'. Would that not make using an index hard or impossible?

Comment: @Asaph: Implicit conversion, where possible, is determined by the column data type.  If `did` is numeric, wouldn't you expect an error for comparing to a string? ;)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The question is: what does the query optimizer actually do? Does it implicitly convert the parameters in the query to ints, or does it implicitly convert every column value in the table to strings? I think that due to the way strings must be compared, it would have to do the latter. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Asaph: Altering the column data type doesn't makes sense -- it's easier to interpret the strings as a number because (assumptions...) the column data type is numeric.  Fire up MySQL & test to see if there's a difference in the EXPLAIN plans.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the input. They are all integers and I tried running the query without quote. But there is no improvement in performance. The main problem is filesort. The query return 10k rows from 10 million row table, and filesorting the 10k rows is a pain.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I did some testing in MySQL and confirmed what you're saying. Stubbornly, I think the choice to convert the strings to ints (potentially lossy) rather than convert ints to strings (not lossy) is, in a logic purist's sense, just plain wrong. But from a practical standpoint, converting strings to ints is pretty much always what the user intended. So I suppose the choice is justified. @Vern: Thanks for trying it out. You should remove the quotes in any case, even if performance did not improve.

Answer (score 4):

Change the index column order. The index is useless for the sort because it'^s the 4th column and isn't ready to be used as-is.

Of course, this affects the usefulness of the index for this WHERE because you need an inequality column before an equality one

In the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html), you break "You use ORDER BY on nonconsecutive parts of a key" and "The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY"

Edit: as per my link above, you can't have an index that satisfies both WHERE and ORDER BY. They are mutually exclusive because of the 2 conditions I posted above

Another suggestion:

- a single column index on id
- go back to the original index too
- remove the index hint
- hope that the optimiser works out that both indexes can be used ("index intersection")

Comment: So what order do you suggest? Perhaps (id, did, type, category)?

Comment: @Vern: The most commonly used column is at the left, second most used would be at the 2nd position, and so on.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Specific to this query, what order will avoid filesort?

Comment: Id first so it matches the sort.

Comment: @gbn: I just tested using 'id' first. It will avoid filesort, BUT for large id, it is doing almost a full row search to retrieve the data, and that is equally insane. @zerkms: category + type + id is the same issue. It will invoke filesort.

Comment: @Vern: why it **will**? I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: @zerkms: You mean an INDEX of the 3 columns right? That's what gbn has explained. id needs to be the first column for ORDER BY to work without sorting.

Comment: @Vern: it shouldn't be the first. Look at the second sample at the link he gave please.

Comment: @zerkms: That's what gbn comment "Id first so it matches the sort." and someone actually voted for that comment. The problem with using Id first is it end up doing an almost complete row search when the Id is large.

Comment: @Vern: omg. Again: `id` SHOULDN'T BE THE FIRST. Pleas read that link **carefully**. And especially second example, which is about key_parts

Comment: @zerkms, @Vern: see my update please. A good search index is a poor sort index and vice versa. Try 2 indexes...

Comment: @gbn: "because of the 2 conditions" --- i'm not sure I understand that correctly, but index `category + type + id` will cover almost everything from where and **is** possible to be used for sorting.

Comment: @zerkms: I see where you're going. The index must cover everything or it'll be ignored (with the hint you'll have a poor plan). Not having `did` means that another index or the table must be read to get it. However, worth a try... :-)

Comment: @gbn: cannot agree with you ;-) Index should not cover everything. mysql will use fast index lookup to find **sorted** values that fits 2 constant values and one range one and will iterate over data table to find exact 10 rows that fits all conditions.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for all the input. Can you tell me what's the difference between 'category + type + id' and my original index of 'category + type + did + id'? Actually, 'category + type + did + id' has been doing a good job for years. But now the table got too big, with 10 million rows. 'category + type + did + id' can quickly return the result to my query, but some results have 10k of data, and because of ORDER BY id DESC, it has to sort through the 10k of data, which is time consuming. I don't see how 'category + type + id' can avoid such sorting.

Comment: The first 2 columns will give one set of sorted ids. When you add "did", then you get several unsorted sets of ids, because of many dids. You could also try category + type + id + did' based on this

Comment: @gbn: `did` as last part of the index is useless, as long as it is index range comparison for `id` and `did` will not be used (at least for such kind of queries)

Comment: @zerkms and @gbn: I have one last question. My table is innoDB and 'id' is actually the Primary key. Does it mean when creating the index, I just have to create (category + type)?

Comment: @Vern: yep, you could try that. As long as it will be clustered index with PK appended automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on id and type it should work for you.
If Id is unique you can also create the Primary Key for it.

your query is using file sort because it might be possible that the optimizer is using the first column of index you created in the query.